# trouble with saving ndarray to text file

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a set of data in the format as below:

name    q1   q2  q3
ER_1   0    0   0
ER_2   0    0   0

I have written a code that does a calculation by reading in this data table and then if the particular calculation concerns one of the names mentioned ex: ER_1 then the q1, q2 and q3 will get updated. I am able to do this and modify the table except that I have trouble saving it in the same format. Here is my attempt which results in a txt file with all elements in a single line i.e. : name,q1,q2,q3,ER_1,0,0,0,ER_2,0,0,0

```
data=numpy.loadtxt('table.txt', dtype=str,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4))#,unpack=True)

NAME='ER_1'

lst=[0,1,2]

for i in lst:
    if NAME in data[i][0]:
        data[i][1] = '27'


data.tofile('newdata.txt',sep=',')
```

[image: the image relates to the first suggestion given]

code as requested:

so you'll need to make a text file called - massout.txt which looks like this:

```
Source   M_ratio  R_ratio   B_ratio   F_tot F_red   F_blue  c3
ER_1     0           0      0         0       0        0     0 
ER_2     0           0      0         0       0        0     0
```

then just copy and run this:

```
massout=numpy.loadtxt('massout.txt', dtype=str,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))#,unpack=True)
source='ER_1'

lst=[0,1,2]

for i in lst:
    if source in massout[i][0]:
        massout[i][1] = '27'


numpy.savetxt('newdata.txt', massout, delimiter='', fmt='%s\n'  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tofile` method writes the data "flattened".  It writes the elements sequentially to the file, losing any shape information about the array.

Your use of the function [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) needs a couple tweaks.  To separate the fields with spaces, use `delimiter=' '` (that's a space character, not an empty string).  Don't include `'\n'` in the `fmt` argument.  The following works for me:

```
numpy.savetxt('newdata.txt', massout, delimiter=' ', fmt='%s')
```

---

*P.S.* With a 2-d numpy array, it is more efficient and stylistically preferable to index the array as `massout[i, j]` instead of `massout[i][j]`.  That is, you should write

```
    massout[i, 1] = '27'
```

instead of

```
    massout[i][1] = '27'
```

Comment: I have included a screen shot of the result of what you suggested. It works except that the data is still on the same line unlike the file that it's reading which you can see is in separate brackets. I tried adding &s\n in the fmt part and the result is the second run as you can see above. Any ideas how I could get the output to look like the input? Cheers!

Comment: Edit your question to show a listing of the *exact* code that you ran (i.e. show `delete.py`), and show the input file (so we can simply copy-and-paste it into a local file and run your code, if necessary).

Comment: Are you sure you included the argument `delimiter=','` in your call of `savetxt`?  (Do you want the output to be comma delimited?  Apparently the input file is not, but you use `sep=','` in your call of the `tofile` method.)

Comment: I have included it now. I want the output to look exactly like my input with the 0 under the M_ratio replaced by a 27, so that the next time I could read this file again just as I read my older input file and update M_ratio whenever I want.